# Elixir: Reduce list to map counting occurrences (pattern match a map key on another argument)

Tags: dictionary, count, duplicates, pattern-matching, elixir

I have a list which may contain duplicates. I want to count how many instances there are of each item in the list. My plan was:

```
list
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn
  item, %{item => count}=acc -> %{acc | item => count + 1}
  item, acc -> Map.put(acc, item, 1)
end)
```

However, this fails to compile with the error `illegal use of variable item inside map key match, maps can only match on existing variable by using ^item`.

So I changed the first pattern to `item, %{^item => count}=acc`. At that point, the error became `unbound variable ^item`.

I'm not sure what to do here. I know it's possible to pattern match one argument based on another (as in `fn a, a -> true` for one head of a comparison function), but apparently not in this case. I tried doing it with guards but `Map.has_key?/2` can't be put in guards. I've found lots of questions here about matching on maps in general, but not about doing so when the value to match on comes from another argument.

Comment: Any reason you didn't use `Map.update/4`? `list |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn x, acc -> Map.update(acc, x, 1, &(&1 + 1)) end)`.

Comment: ... Because I didn't read the docs as thoroughly as I thought I had, apparently. Please make that an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Modifying a value for a key in a Map and inserting if it doesn't already exist is exactly what `Map.update/4` does. To calculate frequencies, the default would be `1` and the update fn would just add 1 to the value (`&(&1 + 1)`):

```
iex(1)> [1, 2, :a, 2, :a, :b, :a] |>
...(1)> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn x, acc -> Map.update(acc, x, 1, &(&1 + 1)) end)
%{1 => 1, 2 => 2, :a => 3, :b => 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a function named [frequencies](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#frequencies/1) in the Enum module that does exactly what you need.

```
iex(1)> [1, 2, :a, 2, :a, :b, :a] |> Enum.frequencies()
%{1 => 1, 2 => 2, :a => 3, :b => 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, found this while writing the question. Figured I'd share it, but if someone else has a cleaner solution they're welcome to it:

The best solution I've found is to... sort of internally curry one of the arguments, so that it's bound, purely for syntactic purposes.

```
list
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn item, acc ->
    f = fn %{item => count}=acc -> %{acc | item => count + 1}
            acc when is_map(acc) -> Map.put(acc, item, 1)
        end
    f.(acc)
  end)
```